# How to run sql script in mysql on Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql. I know I can run script with absolute path:

```
mysql> source /absolute_path/file.sql;
```

Is there a way to use just relative path? Or to simplify the absolute path via some variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a relative path, then it will be relative to the current working directory you were in when you ran the mysql client.

In other words, the following would work:

```
$ cd /absolute_path
$ mysql
mysql> source file.sql
```

I don't think you can use expressions or variables in the `source` command. It's a [builtin command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) to the mysql client, and that has a simpler parser than the MySQL Server's SQL parser. Builtin commands don't support expressions or variables.

Here's a link to the code that parses the `source` command: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc#L4187-L4197